# jump to step 5 (ViewController 5) when login again

Tags: json, swift5, xcode10.3

Explain
My project has many view controller.
my task have step 1-10 (I mean step1 = view controller  1)
And I want check, username if hold work on Step 5 and logout.
and login again by use username last time.

when login  again from login view controller, I want to jump to step 5
Without ignor step 1-4 that has been completed
Please suggest me

Comment: Your translation to English is not clear, perhaps you know of someone who could translate your question better so that you get a proper solution ..

Comment: @Ken sorry, i'm edited i hope you are understand.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remember the last position, the client has been. So you could write it to a file and store this. Have a look at this tutorial:

[How to write to Properties-File](https://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-a-properties-file.html)

on Resume / reopen / relogin (whatever you use to get your user back in to your app), just read the correct property, and redirect him to this controller

Comment: this tutorial not swift5 language, I use swift 5 and xcode10.3